# Problems Configuring TFS 2010 Email Notification with Office 365 Exchange Server

Tags: email, exchange-2010, gmail, microsoft-office-365, team-foundation-server

We are using Office 365 as our Exchange server. Our O365 account is a P1 plan and so our email accounts are not in the same domain as our local TFS accounts.

I have **configured TFS 2010 to use our O365 Exchange server** (same server address that Outlook is using), but of course there is no UI to enter the account credentials (only server address and email account to use). Therefore, the following error message in the event log is not surprising:

> Detailed Message: TF271001: An error occurred while attempting to send
>   an e-mail notification to the following address:
>   schmid@economicasystems.com. Further e-mail notification errors that
>   occur within the next five minutes might not be logged. Verify that
>   the e-mail notification settings are correct in the Team Foundation
>   Administration Console. Exception Message: The SMTP server requires a
>   secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server
>   response was: **5.7.1 Client was not authenticated** (type SmtpException)

Is there a way to **configure TFS2010** to use an **email server that needs authentication credentials** (such as O365 or GMail)?

**Edit:**
It appears that the information can be added/edited in **TfsJobAgent.exe.config**. So far I have not been able to successfully use a GMail account for the email relay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unfortunately not supported by TFS 2010. You need to either setup a SMTP server, or an SMTP relay server to forward your outgoing emails, with authentication, to your 'real' SMTP server.

These links might help:

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;324285

http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=147049&SiteID=1

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsserver2008r2general/thread/1c3957c7-d98d-43d6-a080-0915bba5ca09/